# Mkdir permission denied php nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I Tried create dir with php code `mkdir($folder, 777, true);`, but return `mkdir(): Permission denied`,  how i can solve this ?

Obs: I using: nginx, php7-fpm and owner folder www is www-data

Comment: Can you please post the details. You've mentioned that you've tried to make it, but not mentioned how. Please post it, and we may be able to help.

Comment: I tried make it using mkdir command php in code.

Comment: Can you please post how you made it?

Comment: mkdir($folder, 777, true);

Comment: Thanks, can you please add that in your question.

Comment: i think this is because the server process (apache2 or nginx) don't have permissions to write to the current directory. Can you check on that?

Comment: how i can see this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
mkdir($folder, 777, true);
```

Add a zero before `777`, It may solve the problem:

```
mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
```

Also, check with your localhost publish permissions.